# Prevent back from showing the homescreen - Android notifications

Tags: android, notifications, back-stack

I have a notification that opens an activity.
After I click that notification, the activity opens.
When I press back, I ALWAYS get to the home screen.

I know that this is the desired behavior using [TaskStackBuilder](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#SimpleNotification), but I do not wish for this behavior. 
I tried not using TaskStackBuilder, and using a normal PendingIntent instead

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, 0);
```

But the same thing happens.

How do I prevent clicking the notification from showing the home screen on back?

Comment: Just a clarification, as you said that this occurs when you're on GMail app, does this happen in every other apps?

Comment: sure it does. that was just an example

Answer (score 1):

The [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html) tells us that as of 2.0 you can override what happens when the back button is pressed.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do something on back.
    return;
}
```

Perhaps you can accomplish what you want from here.

Comment: This does not help... say I am in the Gmail app, and I click on my app's notification. clicking on back will show the home screen and there is nothing I can do in onBackPressed to prevent that